# Insert data into table and use that data to create view

Tags: mysql, sql

When there is request from user i get parameter `x`,`y`,`flag` and `sent`. I insert it into `table2`.

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO table2 
         (id,sent,pcount,ncount,flag)
         VALUES
         ('".$_POST['id']."','".$_POST['sent']."',' $x ','$y','$flag')";
```

When data is inserted, below that I am showing chart, which takes inserted values `x` and `y` to show the chart.

So how on button click event I can get the values inserted in last `insert` operation??

Is it possible that I can create view with last row x and y values from table `table2`.

Table `table2` has auto increment column.

Comment: Yes its possible to create view with last values.

Comment: @Mihai: thanks, can you please tell me how. Probably new answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT xcolumn,ycolumn
FROM table2 WHERE id=SELECT MAX(id)
```

Assuming you have an incrementing column called id.

Comment: Buna, Mihai. What if the max id is not the last one inserted?

Comment: Heh,salut.Yes there is also this assumption.

Comment: @Vlad: If id is auto increment then always max(id) will give last one inserted, right? I am not sure

Comment: Yes but you want the last inserted from your script,other scripts might insert something incrementing the id.

Comment: If no other script exist then ok?

Comment: And no other insert except the one you posted.

Comment: It's the connection. So if the page is accessed by more than one browser at a time you run risk of having a max id that is not the same as the one you just inserted.

Comment: Yes, probably you right Vlad, but for each page access I want to show user the inserted value by him only. then any alternative?

Comment: Why don't you associate his post with his name?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from the last insert, use last_insert_id().  This will give you the last inserted id for your connection.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: `CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT xcolumn,ycolumn
FROM table2 WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID();` currect?

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused about what you need. If you create a view like this, you will have a view with just the last row inserted. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I want to create chart for last inserted values only!

Comment: Then that should do it. Do you really need the view for that? Why not just do the select?

Comment: `SELECT xcolumn,ycolumn FROM table2 WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID();` will also work I think!